# Error "missing DVI driver" in tabularht?

Tags: tables, dvi

I'm using `\usepackage[vlines]{tabularht}` and got this error:

```
! Package tabularht Error: Missing DVI driver, option `vlines' disabled.
See the tabularht package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

What does this error mean?

Below is the entire code of my doc. I'm trying to stretch a table to fit the remaining space on the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[vlines]{tabularht}

\begin{document}
\section{Change the improper fractions to a mixed number.}
\begin{tabularhtx}{\textheight-0.55in}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\interrowfill
$\dfrac{29}{3}$ & $\dfrac{30}{4}$\\
\interrowfill
\hline
\interrowfill
$\dfrac{22}{5}$ & $\dfrac{48}{5}$\\
\interrowfill
\hline
\end{tabularhtx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the second line of the error message?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Option `vlines` is driver dependent and uses e-TeX features.
>
> **pdftex:** pdfTeX in PDF mode. Here the positions of the lines are written with the
>          help of the `\pdfsavepos` feature into the .aux file(s). Therefore you need
>          two LaTeX runs to get the lines.
>
> **dvips:** Here, PostScript's `currentpoint` it used to get the line positions. The lines
>          are then drawn at the end of the page. Thus one LaTeX/dvips run is sufficient
>          for this option.

The package automatically detects pdfTeX in PDF mode (driver option `pdftex`. But `dvips` runs *after* the LaTeX run and the package cannot know, which DVI driver is used (`dvips`, `dvipdfmx`, ...).

Comment: Hopefully you won't get mad at me, but to be fair even I did not understand immediately that the driver has to be declared as package option. (Upvote nonetheless...)

Comment: @campa In case of pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX in PDF mode, it should not be necessary to specify the driver, because the TeX compilers and the mode can be detected at TeX level. In case of DVI, TeX cannot know, which driver runs in the future *after* the TeX compile run has finished, unless it gets informed by a driver option, for example.